# How do I update Flutter's Riverpod values from business logic?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

When using Flutter and Riverpod, how do I update its values from my business logic?

I understand that I can get and set values from the UI side.

```
class XxxNotifier extends StateNotifier<String> {
  XxxNotifier() : super("");
}

final xxxProvider = StateNotifierProvider<XxxNotifier, int>((ref) {
  return XxxNotifier();
});

class MyApp extends HookConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // getValue
    final String value = ref.watch(xxxProvider);

    // setValue
    context.read(xxxProvider).state = "val";

    return Container();
  }
}
```

This method requires a context or ref.

How do I get or set these states from the business logic side?

Passing a context or ref from the UI side to the business logic side might do that, but I saw no point in separating the UI and business logic. Perhaps another method exists.

Perhaps I am mistaken about something. You can point it out to me.

Comment: what you are doing is not a business logic. its a UI logic and there is no point on using StateNotifier for storing only string. Use stateProvider instead.

Comment: We cannot share the real code due to NDA. This is just a sample. It is actually status of various types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `ref` in your `XxxNotifier` class:

```dart
class XxxNotifier extends StateNotifier<String> {
  XxxNotifier(this._ref) : super("");

  final Ref _ref;

  void setNewState() {
    state = 'to setting';
    // use `_ref.read` to read state other provider
  }
}

final xxxProvider = StateNotifierProvider<XxxNotifier, int>((ref) {
  return XxxNotifier(ref);
});

// or using tear-off
final xxxProvider = StateNotifierProvider<XxxNotifier, int>(XxxNotifier.new);
```

Comment: Yes, I do. We know we can do that by passing ref. We want to know if that is the right way to use it or if there is a better way.

Comment: Basically, we can't get the state of the provider without using `ref`. This method is recommended by the author of the package.

Comment: I see. Then we can pass ref to StateNotifier and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create methods in your XxxNotifier class to modify the state of your provider.

For example, your notifier class can look like this.

```js
class TodosNotifier extends StateNotifier <List<Todo>> {
  TodosNotifier(): super([]);

  void addTodo(Todo todo) {
    state = [...state, todo];
  }

}
```

You can then read the provider in a callback.

```
ref.read(xxxProvider.notifier).addTodo(todo);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very helpful. But we wanted to know about how to refer to it from business logic . Do we still have to pass the ref?

Comment: You can pass the ref as it is done in the docs: 
https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#obtaining-a-ref-from-a-provider

Comment: Thank you. That's the correct way to implement it since it's written in the example in the documentation.